# Mute and unmute command in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a mute command. The code below doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't work.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member : discord.Member) :
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = member
    global mute_role

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "MUTED" :
            if role in user.roles:
                await ctx.send(f'**{user.name} is already muted!**')
            else:
             await member.add_roles(role)
            await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been muted by {ctx.author} ")

            for role in guild.roles:

             if role.name == "MUTED" not in guild.roles:
                mute_role = await guild.create_role(name="MUTED")

        perms = discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=False)

        for channel in guild.text_channels :
            await channel.set_permissions(mute_role, overwrite=perms)

            if role.name == "MUTED" not in user.roles:
              await member.add_roles(mute_role)
              await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been muted by {ctx.author.mention}')
              return
```

I have tried multiple methods and "played around" with the variables but I have not managed to make a functional command. I would also like to make a timed mute command, but first I need to make this work.
I have searched for other mute commands on StackOverflow but I could not find anything functional or decent.
Also, if I am able to make this work, how would I go about making an unmute command too?

Answer (score 1):

Well I know it is probably too late, but here is my mute command:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    guild = ctx.guild
    if role not in guild.roles:
      perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, speak=False)
      await guild.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=perms)
      await member.add_roles(role)
      await ctx.send("Successfully created Muted role and assigned it to mentioned user.")
    else:
      await member.add_roles(role) 
      await ctx.send(f"Successfully muted ({member})")

@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the 'staff' role") 
@mute.error
async def mute_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("That is not a valid member")
```

I, too,  need an unmute command.

Comment: How did you arrive to this solution?

Comment: Idk I did it a while ago... But it works!

Comment: well, in the meantime i managed to learn more about discord.py and made my own temp mute/unmute commands, but thanks for your answer