# Can not seem to get mute commands to work with Discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I can not find a mute command for my discord bot, and I do not know how to write one. The tutorials and pieces of code out there are not working. The most recent code produces no errors messages, but the command will not initiate. How?

````
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.member, *, reason=None):
  guild =ctx.guild
  mutedRole = discord.Utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
  if not mutedRole == await guild.create_role(name="Muted"):
    for channel in guild.channels:
      await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, sendmessages=False, read_message_history=False, read_messages=False)
  await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason = reason)
  await ctx.send(f"Muted {member.mention} for reason {reason}")
  await member.send(f"You were muted in {guild.name} for {reason}")```
````

Comment: "No actual errors" So it works? Or do you mean that it produces no error messages?

Comment: The 'u' in `discord.Utils` is in CAPS; change it to `discord.utils`. @ctrl-alt-delor, yes, it doesn't produce any error messages, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you have a role named 'Muted'?

Comment: The messages are not the errors. Someone put in a lot of effort writing code to detect errors, and to tell you what they are. Unfortunately not all errors can be detected.

Comment: @The-Amateur-Coder I changed the 'U' to 'u' and there is still no outcome, and yes I have a "Muted" role

Comment: Probably your `on_message` can interrupt the processing of other commands. Not sure how similar these checks are to `bot.command` decorator.

Comment: Discords has built in muting now (time out), you shouldn't need a Muted role.  There seems to be info for the API here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70444041/time-out-via-discord-api

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128213/mute-command-not-working-no-error-message-discord-python.

Comment: What about reformatting the mute command to make it [a normal command that performs the permission checks inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227408/mute-and-unmute-command-in-discord-py)?

Comment: Why is there no error? Try looking at the logs, or `async def on_command_error(ctx, err): print(err)` to see where the error actually is - it might be silently ignored.

Comment: It still doesn't show any errors. There are many mistakes and typos in the code. The fix was adding a `@bot.command()` before it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve]. This code is not runnable

Answer (score -1):

There are many mistakes and typos in the code. Adding [`@bot.command(name=name)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) before `@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)` fixed it for me:

```py
intent = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="", description="", intents=intent) 
#See if you have "intents=<someintentobject>" and enable them in your Discord Developer Portal


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("It's online!")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) #Let the commands process the message


@bot.command(name="mute") #This decorator tells that the mute function is a command the bot should process
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True) #Run the mute command only if the message's author has the permission to manage messages
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None): #Removed the extra arguments' asterisk (*)
#It's discord.Member, not discord.member
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted") #utils, not Utils
    if not mutedRole == await guild.create_role(name="Muted"):
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=False,
                                          read_messages=False) #send_messages, not sendmessages
    await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Muted {member.mention} for reason {reason}")
    await member.send(f"You were muted in {guild.name} for {reason}")
```

[Add `await bot.process_commands(message)` in your `on_message`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208333/16136190)

I've removed the `*` (`args`); it works fine without it. You can add it if you want.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443946/16136190) of a kick command.

Comment: first of all, you don't need an on_message event if you don't use it . the process commands part is only for commands inside the on_message.

Comment: @Ares, what do you mean? The OP probably has an `on_message`. I included that part because it's the de facto way to respond to and process *all* messages. Also, `bot.process_commands(<message>)` processes *all* registered commands. See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands.

Answer (score -1):

```
 @bot.command()
 @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
 async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    
    if member == ctx.author:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red(),
            description="You can't mute yourself !"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    muterole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="MUTED")
    if muterole is None:
        muterole = await ctx.guild.create_role(name="MUTED")

        for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(muterole, overwrite=discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=False))

    if muterole in member.roles:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.red(),
            description=f'This member is already muted'
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    await member.add_roles(muterole)
    embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Colour.green(),
            title=' Muted',
            description=f'**{member.mention}** is now  **permanently muted** reason: **{reason}**.'
        )
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Muted by {ctx.author}.')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

basically what a "mute" command does is to create or directly assign a role to a member, the most important part is that the mute role to be correctly configured.
there's also more complex methods of mute command, for example temp mute command which allows you to mute someone for a certain amount of time specified by the mod, but these days is recommended that you use the `timeout` feature is a lot easier and more efficient. but there you have it, a basic mute command with the appropriate checks.