# CTX commands not working when combined with the mcstatus library

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, minecraft

I made a Discord bot that tells you a Minecraft's server status!
It works fine on the console with the `print` function, but it doesn’t work as a command! The bot just doesn’t respond. Also I tested it without the `mcstatus` library and the command worked. (Without what it's supposed to do, of course.)

This is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from mcstatus import JavaServer

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
client.remove_command("help")

server = JavaServer.lookup("mc.elitesmp.co:25588")
status = server.status()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as: "' + str(client.user) + '"')
    print(f"Elite SMP has {status.players.online} players online!")

@client.command() # <--- This is the command that doesn't work!
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("test")

client.run("token")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Im guessing this has to do with the fact that I used the server or status variable but without them the `mcstatus` functions dont work!

Comment: Are you using discordpy 2.0.0? You might need the proper intents. Also, be aware that `mcstatus` is non-async and can block (and potentially break) the code.

Comment: What happens if you add `print('starting')` immediately before `client.run`? Is `on_ready` executing?

Comment: @EricJin Yes, it does execute just fine. Also, what do you mean non-async? Is there anyway I could fix it or is it not fixable?

Comment: @Bella, do you have a line like `intent = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True)`? You should create your bot using `bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intent)`. (with the intent as a parameter)
See if you have enabled the [necessary intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) in your Discord Developer Portal. [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72327971/16136190) can probably help.

Comment: @Bella It's not really something you can fix. But you can re-implement the protocol minecraft uses with async requests (`aiohttp`). This might be the problem, but either way checking the status shouldn't suck out ALL the processor time of your bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it’s because you need to enable intents in your Discord bot, and also declare them in the code by adding:

`intents = discord.Intents.default()`

And also putting `, intents=intents` in the space where you declare your bot's prefix.

This is also an example of a bot I just made, to help with some command also.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from mcstatus import JavaServer
from mcstatus import BedrockServer


intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)

TOKEN = "removed for obvious reasons"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching,name="Minecraft Servers"))

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error,commands.CommandInvokeError):
        await ctx.reply("No such server was found")

@bot.command()
async def java(ctx, message):
    server = JavaServer.lookup(message)
    status = server.status()
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}", description=f"info on {message}")
    embed.add_field(name="Players Online :green_circle:", value=f"The server has {status.players.online} players online", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Server Response :warning:", value=f"The server replied in {status.latency}ms", inline=False)
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def bedrock(ctx, message):
    server = BedrockServer.lookup("message")
    status = server.status()
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}", description=f"info on {message}")
    embed.add_field(name="Players Online :green_circle:", value=f"The server has {status.players.online} players online", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Server Response :warning:", value=f"The server replied in {status.latency}ms", inline=False)
    await ctx.reply(embed=embed)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The following code works fine for me, as you can see here.

The following image shows how the commands work: [command image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZnBn.png)

Comment: Hey, this indeed worked, but I have a question. When I tested it without any intents and without the `mcstatus` library, the commands worked fine! With the `mcstatus` library on however, the commands did not work. Why is that? (with my own code, not yours.)

Answer (score -1):

I think the command isn't working, because you haven't declared what intents you need in code. Discord bots now need to declare what events they need to access, such as reading messages. You can read about intents in the *discord.py* documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

I also moved the "players online" part to a variable, and printed that instead, and that got your command to work.

```
 intents = discord.Intents.default()
 client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents = intents)
 client.remove_command("help")

 player_text = f"Elite SMP has {status.players.online} players online!"

 @client.event
 async def on_ready():
     print(player_text)

 @client.command()
 async def test(ctx):
     await ctx.send("test")
```

Screenshots of it working in code [here](https://strasbourg.ovh-fire.cloud/Lq8fxfdd) and Discord [here](https://strasbourg.ovh-fire.cloud/bxB6qtTh).

Comment: Although helpful, this does not fix it. Even if it did, it wouldn't make sense that it works without the mcstatus library and doesnt with it. There has to be something with the mcstatus library that is messing with the command!

Comment: @Bella Sorry, try `{status.players_online}` instead. Is it definitely a Java server?

Comment: what? as i meantioned in my question, it shows the players online just fine, the problem is that the commands dont run. Also, according to the mcstatus docs, its `{status.players.online}` changing the dot to an underscore, will just break it.

Comment: wait no sorry, I actually found a fix, lemme update the main msg

Comment: Still doesn't work. you keep changing the event not the command. also, what you did is useless as it did no change. __The event works fine, the command doesnt work.__

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me: here's a screenshot of the [code](https://strasbourg.ovh-fire.cloud/Lq8fxfdd) and result in [discord](https://strasbourg.ovh-fire.cloud/bxB6qtTh)

Comment: thats very weird, I used the same code as you and the bot still doesnt reply. I tried adding it on another server yet it still doesnt work, it has admin perms so I dont see how it works on you and not me, im not doing anything diffrently

Comment: are you getting any errors when you try run the command?

Comment: no i dont, i have the latest discord.py and python version aswell

Comment: The latest discord.py version would require `intents.message_content` to be enabled, not only the default.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, I prefer to specify it when making the Intent object itself. Something like `intent = discord.Intents(messages=True, message_content=True, guilds=True)`. It said attributes like `message_content` (of `intents`) are read-only when I tried to create the intent without passing any parameters and then changing its attributes to `True`/`False`. Also, I think only `message_content` won't be enough, for there is `status.players.online`, that'd need some others too, something like `guilds`.

Comment: Sorry, `status.players.online` doesn't need any extra intents as it's not related to Discord's API but to MCStatus'. `message_content` would probably be more than enough.

Comment: Perhaps rephrase slightly? At first glance it *looks* like a plagiarised version of Skelly's answer (it isn't).